# How to get page status with firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to get page status codes like 40* or 30*. Firefox extension can get status when page loaded, when content_script.js executed. But content script not executed when page not loaded (3xx or 4xx errors).
How to check that the tab with a specific URL is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to handle the onHeadersReceived event in your background.js. You can refer the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived).

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    if(!details.initiator)
    {
        alert(details.url+" "+details.statusCode);
    }
},
{
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
},
["responseHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

In your manifest.json you need to add

```
"permissions": ["webRequest","webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"],
```

Comment: You way work only if page loaded, and work with resourses, loaded by page. I want receive status of page, that i type in browser address bar

Comment: details.statusCode will give you the status code of the loaded resource like 200, 404 and so on. If you are getting the status codes for all the resources then retry again with my latest answer. It will give the status code only for the URL which you try to load. Other resources will be ignored. It works fine for me.

Comment: details.statusCode works only if page loaded and loads media from another hosts. If i type url in address bar and that url load with 50* error (server errors) then details.statusCode not works